# How to add an integer to a set while iterating?

Tags: java, iterator, set

I have a set of sets of integers: `Set<Set<Integer>>`.
I need to add integers to the set of sets as if it were a double array. So add(2,3) would have to add integer 3 to the 2nd set. 
I know a set is not very suitable for this operation but it's not my call.
The commented line below clearly does not work but it shows the intention.

My question is how to add an integer to a set while iterating?
If it's necessary to identify each set, how would one do this?

```
@Override
public void add(int a, int b) {
    if (!isValidPair(a, b)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("!isValidPair does not hold for (a,b)");
    }

    Iterator<Set<Integer>> it = relation.iterator();
    int i = 0;

    while (it.hasNext() && i <= a) {
        //it.next().add(b);
          i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The commented line below clearly does not work" - please elaborate.

Comment: I agree: a set isn't a suitable data structure when talking about "order" of entries. And "does not work" is not a description of a problem that would work when looking for help.

Comment: Appologies, the commented line gives a  java.util.NoSuchElementException (but does compile).

Answer (score 1):

One fundamental things you should be aware of, for which makes all existing answer in this question not working:

Once an object is added in a `Set` (similarly, as key in `Map`), it is not supposed to change (at least not in aspects that will change its `equals()` and `hashCode()`).  The "Uniqueness" checking is done only when you add the object into the `Set`.

For example

```
Set<Set<Integer>> bigSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> v1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2));
bigSet.add(v1);

System.out.println("contains " + bigSet.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2))));  // True

v1.add(3);

System.out.println("contains " + bigSet.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2))));    // False!!
System.out.println("contains " + bigSet.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))));  // False!!
```

You can see how the set is corrupted. It contains a `[1,2,3]` but `contains()` does not work, neither for `[1,2]` nor `[1,2,3]`.

Another fundamental thing is, your so-called '2nd set' may not make sense.  `Set` implementation like `HashSet` maintain the values in arbitrary order.

So, with these in mind, what you may do is:

1. First find the n-th value, and remove it
2. add the value into the removed value set
3. re-add the value set.

Something like this (pseudo code again):

```
int i = 0;
Set<Integer> setToAdd = null;
for (Iterator itr = bigSet.iterator; itr.hasNext(); ++i) {
    Set<Integer> s = itr.next();
    if (i == inputIndex) {
        // remove the set first
        itr.remove();
        setToAdd = s;
        break;
    }
}

// update the set and re-add it back
if (setToAdd != null) {
    setToAdd.add(inputNumber);
    bigSet.add(setToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use can use `Iterators` of [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1) library like this :

```
@Override
public void add(int a, int b) {
    if (!isValidPair(a, b)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("!isValidPair does not hold for (a,b)");
    }

    Iterators.get(relation.iterator(), a).add(b);
}
```

Edit : without Guava:

```
Iterator<Set<Integer>> iterator = relation.iterator();

for(int i = 0; i < a && iterator.hasNext(); ++i) {
    iterator.next();
}
if(iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next().add(b);
}
```

Comment: tempting. But I don't think I'm allowed to use downloaded libraries.
Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The iterator solution will break if the loop condition `iterator.hasNext()` fails before the integer comparison. I realize we're supposed to assume that the black-box `isValidPair` method takes care of that, but we don't see the evidence of that here. Having a separate method for boundary checking is a touch of overengineering in this scenario.

Comment: mutating the value that you have put in a Set is going to corrupt the Set

Comment: @Adrian are you sure about this ? how it's going to corrupt the Set ?

Comment: @Lew adding another `if(iterator.hasNext())` should solve it right?

Comment: Check my answer. For example in a HashSet, it is going to make the value put under a wrong bucket.

Comment: @MouadELFakir I have updated my answer to include an actual example that you can try out, which demonstrate how the `Set` is corrupted if you have changed the value after adding it to the set.

Answer (score -1):

Use a for-each loop and make your life easier.

```
public boolean add(int index, int value) {
// because a and b suck as variable names

  if (index < 0 || index >= values.size()) {
    return false;
  }

  int iter = 0;
  for (Set<Integer> values : relation) {
    if (iter++ == index) {
      return values.add(value):
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now all you have to figure out is what to do if `relation` is unordered, as a `Set` or a relation are, because in that case a different `Set<Integer>` could match the same `index` each time the loop executes.

Comment: mutating the value that you have put in a Set is going to corrupt the Set.